# How to use Apache Jmeter in a localhost web server?

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, jmeter, localhost

I am really new in load testing and I'm currently using the Apache Jmeter 2.13 (I downloaded a lower version so that I can relate with the tutorials and manuals in the web)

So here's my situation: I am using XAMPP as my localhost web server (I already copied my application's folder to the htdocs).
I followed this tutorial https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf, and then here's my questions:

1. In the **HTTP Request Defaults**, I inputted *localhost/attendance* (attendance is the name of my program's folder in htdocs) in the **Server Name or IP** field. Is it correct?
2. Did I follow the right manual for my expedition? What I mean is that, is it really possible to use Jmeter in testing a localhost database in phpMyadmin? If so, how would I do it?

Thank you so much. I hope somebody can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're reading the right document. I would recommend also familiarise yourself with [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) User Manual entry

I wouldn't recommend load testing your database via phpmyadmin as it is just a database GUI designed for being used by a single person. You should be building a realistic test scenario mimicking your application real-life usage. And avoid running JMeter and application under test at the same machine as in case of resources lack like CPU, RAM, Network or Disk IO it will he quite hard to tell what is consuming resources, either your application or JMeter.

The general recommendation is to focus on HTTP protocol level, i.e. main load coming from [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and if you find that the database is the bottleneck - you can consider [standalone database testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter).

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

can you please have a look in to the given link? This may help you.
http://www.tothenew.com/blog/building-mysql-database-test-plan-using-jmeter/

Comment: Thank you, but can I ask again? Is the same instructions applicable even if I'm using phpmyadmin?